# How to show that $n^{\ln(\ln(n))} = \ln(n)^{\ln(n)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I have verified that $n^{\ln(\ln(n))} = \ln(n)^{\ln(n)}$ by plugging in values for $n$, but do not understand why it is true. I am not aware of any $\log$ rules that can be used to simplify $n^{\ln(\ln(n))}$.

Comment: Try the rule that $a^b=e^{b\ln a}$.

Comment: More generally $a^{\ln b} = b^{\ln a}$.

Comment: Take a natural log of both sides.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that $n=e^{\ln n}$ so

$$n^{\ln (\ln n)}=e^{\ln n\cdot \ln(\ln n)}=(\ln n)^{\ln n}$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that if we can prove

$$a^{\log_b{c}}=c^{\log_b{a}}$$

then we have proved your problem with $a=n$, $b=e$, and $c=\ln{n}$.

We now do just that. Let $a, b, c$ be arbitrary real numbers. Notice that $b^{\log_b{a}}=a$. Also notice that $(x^y)^z=x^{yz}$ for real numbers $x,y,z$. With these two facts in hand we have that

\begin{align}
  a^{\log_b{c}} &=
  (b^{\log_b{a}})^{\log_b{c}} \\
  &= b^{(\log_b{a})(\log_b{c})} \\
  &= b^{(\log_b{c})(\log_b{a})} \\
  &= (b^{\log_b{c}})^{\log_b{a}} \\
  &= c^{\log_b{a}}
\end{align}

And so we are done.

Answer (score -1):

Following Cameron Williams' hint, we take the logarithm of both sides to get

$$\ln \left(n^{\ln\left(\ln (n)\right)}\right) = \ln \left( \ln (n)^{\ln (n)}\right)$$

Recall that $\log_b a^c = c\log_b a$. Use this property on both sides:

$$\left(\ln\left(\ln(n)\right)\right)\left(\ln(n)\right)=\left(\ln(n)\right)\left(\ln\left(\ln(n)\right)\right)$$

This is true because multiplication is commutative.

Comment: Did I mess something up?

Comment: I personally believe that correct answers should never be downvoted.  Obviously, not everyone on SE believes this.